Calculating the last payday depending on annual / quarterly due dates of regular invoices
For regular annual and quarterly invoices, I set aside suitable partial amounts each month and use Excel to validate the current balance of these partial amounts. I take the due date of the first invoice as the basis for the calculation. I then calculate the last payday using the following rules:

The day of the payday is always the 25th.
To determine the month, I check whether the first invoice's due date was on the 25th of the month or later. If so, the month is taken from the due date. Otherwise, the payday was in the previous month.
The year of the last payday is determined depending on today's date. If the payment has already been made this year, then the year of the last payday is the current one. Otherwise, the payment was made in the previous year.
For quarterly invoices, today's date must also be used to determine the month.
A single partial amount is the total amount divided by the period (12 or 3 months)
Putting a partial amount aside also happens always on the 25th.

Having the date of the last payday makes the calculation of the number of partial amounts very simple - it is the number of months between today and the date of the last payment multiplied by the single partial amount.
Solution
Annual invoices
Now I will describe my current solution for the annual invoices. Let's assume that the due date of the first invoice is in cell A2 and the “today's” date is in cell J1.
With this formula, I first determine the payday in the current year:
B2=DATE(YEAR($J$1),IF(DAY(A2)>=25,MONTH(A2),MONTH(A2)-1), "25")

Then I calculate the last payday. In case, the invoice hasn't been paid this year yet, I subtract one year from the payment in the current year. To get exactly one year (some years are leap years) I calculate a date difference between today and today minus one year:
F2=IF(B2>$J$1,B2-DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($J$1)-1,MONTH($J$1),DAY($J$1)),$J$1, “D”),B2)

The calculation of the number of partial amounts then looks as follows:
G2=DATEDIF(C2,$J$1, “M”)

And we're done with the annual part here.

Quarterly invoices
My solution to handle the quarterly calculations is somewhat cumbersome. To calculate the last payday I again use the date of the payment in the current year and add or subtract a corresponding number of months to it. This number of months is calculated like this, B9 contains the payday in the current year:
C9=INT(MOD(MONTH($J$1)-MONTH(B9)-1,12)/3)*3`

Then I calculate the number of days to be subtracted from this year's payday and this is where it gets ugly:
D9=IF($J$1>B9,
      -DATEDIF($J$1,DATE(YEAR($J$1),MONTH($J$1)+C9,DAY($J$1)),"D"),
      DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR($J$1)-1,MONTH($J$1)+C9,DAY($J$1)),$J$1,"D"))

If we already passed this year's payday it's negative of the diff between today and today plus the number of months calculated above. Otherwise, it's the diff between today minus one year plus the number of months calculated above and today.
Then just subtract D9 from this year's payday and calculate the amount of parts on its basis:
E9=B9-D9
F9=DATEDIF(E9,$J$1, “M”)


Improvements
There are several flaws with my solution that need improvement:

The calculation does not take weekends and public holidays into account. If the 25th of a month is on a weekend or a public holiday, the last payday should be moved earlier accordingly. For example, 25.08.2024 is a Sunday and an annual invoice was originally due on 25.08.23, then the payay in 2024 is 23.08.

When calculating annual invoices, leap years are taken into account correctly because a diff is used for today's date. However, this does not work for quarterly invoices. Depending on the situation, the day of the last payday is determined somewhere between the 24th and the 27th. This should always be the 25th with the exception of weekends and public holidays.

Overall, the solution can certainly be simplified and optimized.



I will not write code for you, but the weekends and public holidays can be done with VBA function.  Create an array of holidays and rules, and given a date, return the effective date.

A2 is called Due date that means you need to have paid then. Why calculate what's already there, or am I misled by this not being 1 question, but really several in one?

@P.b A2 is called "First due date". The due date for the first invoice. It's about regular invoices that I receive annually or quarterly.

I'm trying to assist but I'm getting lost in this.  "I set aside suitable partial amounts each month" Are you making payments or receiving payments? Why is it important to adjust for leap years if your target is the 25th which always exists?  Is there some benefit I'm missing?

@Blindspots Sorry when my wording isn't perfect. I receive annual bills that I have to pay. So that the amount doesn't hurt, I set aside 1/12 of the amount each month. Regarding the leap year, I don't remember exactly but I had issues that the result was not always the 25th. Since I cannot reproduce anymore, we can ignore it for now.

Ty for responding. Do the payments have an actual start and end date or do they really start in 2010 and go on forever?  What is the relevance of the 25th? Just trying to better understand the  XY Problem

The invoices theoretically have no end date. They must be paid as long as contracts exist. Let's say I have a premium subscription to an online store that costs me $X per year. Then I pay $X every year as long as I have this subscription.

The 25th is relevant for me because that's when I receive my salary.

...or a couple of days before the 25th in case of public holidays and weekends

What's the version of Excel you're using?

I use both Office 2013 and 365

German Locale (NA at the bottom)
=LET(
   RNG;A:A; HLDAY;M:M; RTDAY;TODAY();
   TDAY;IFERROR(1/(1/(J1*K2));RTDAY);
   COL;LAMBDA(n; OFFSET(RNG; 1; n-1; COUNTIF(RNG;">0")));
   IN;COL(1); AMT;COL(2); AN;COL(3);
   PDS;BYROW(SEQUENCE(36;1;-18); LAMBDA(n;  LET(
     d;EOMONTH(TDAY;n)+26-SEQUENCE(14);
     MAX(FILTER(d;(WEEKDAY(d;2)<6)*NOT(COUNTIF(HLDAY;d)))))));
   PD;MIN(FILTER(PDS;PDS>=TDAY));
   QO;ABS(MOD(MONTH(IN);3)-MOD(MONTH(PD);3));
   NIN;MAP(IN; AN; QO; LAMBDA(i;a;q; LET(
     d;DATE(YEAR(PD);IF(a; MONTH(i); MONTH(PD)+q); DAY(i));
     IF(d<PD; EDATE(d; a*9+3); d))));
   LIN;MAP(NIN; AN; LAMBDA(i;a; EDATE(i; a*-9-3)));
   CALC;LAMBDA(d;l; MAX(FILTER(PDS; (PDS<=d)*((PDS>=PD)+l))));
   VNIN;MAP(NIN; AN; LAMBDA(i;a; IFERROR(CALC(i;); CALC(EDATE(i; a*9+3);))));
   VLIN;MAP(LIN; LAMBDA(i; CALC(i;1)));
   MDIF;LAMBDA(d; DATEDIF(EOMONTH(VLIN;1)+1; EOMONTH(d;1)+1;"M"));
   TRM;MDIF(VNIN); MACCR;MDIF(PD); PCT;MACCR/TRM; EUR;PCT*AMT;
   DUE;SUM((VNIN=PD)*EUR);
   FRAC;RIGHT(" "& MACCR; 2)& LEFT(" ("& TRM& ") "; 5);
   IFNA(VSTACK(
     HSTACK("Aligned Payroll Date¹";"Accrued²";"PCT";"Months";"";"Today");
     HSTACK(VNIN; EUR; PCT; FRAC; "";
       VSTACK(
         RTDAY;"";"Payday/Pay Period Ending³"; PD;"";
        "Total Due";DUE;"";"Total Due & Accrued";SUM(EUR);"";
         "¹Pay Period closest to (but not after) invoice due date";
         "²100% when 'Payment Due' = 'Payday'";
         "³First weekday (non-holiday) from the 25th backward.")));""))



RNG is the column used for testing if rows are populated
HLDAY is a reference to the holiday exclusion list.
COL is a LAMBDA function that returns a data column. It takes one argument n, a column number (should be tweaked if RNG isn't in column 1). It's offset 1 row to skip the labels.
TDAY is either the "real" today RTDAY which is equal to TODAY() or an override date which is the product of the date override checkbox J1 and the override date in K2. NB: A date value is expected in K2 but is only validated as a non-zero number. For example, 10 would be accepted as the date 10.JAN.1900.
IN, AMT, and AN is the original Invoice Dates,  their  amounts, and the state of the Annual (vs. quarterly) checkboxes.
PDS stores an array of valid payroll dates, a year and a half in the past and future, skipping weekends and holidays.
PD is the closest payday in PDS that is >=TDAY
QO stores an array of quarter offsets which is the number of months to offset PD's month in order to land on a month matching the invoice's quarterly cycle. QO would be either 0, 1, or 2. The three quarterly cycle groups  are 1,4,7,10 or 2,5,8,11 or 3,6,9,12.
NIN is an array of next invoice dates calculated by mapping IN, AN, and QO into a LAMBDA row by row. The LAMBDA stores the current values in i, a, q, respectively, and the LAMDA's formula then:

Creates a date d using the year from PD and, if an annual invoice a, then the original invoice's month i, otherwise the month from PD plus the quarter offset QO.
Checks if date d is less than PD and if so returns d after first bumping it to the next year/quarter (based on a). If not then d is returned unchanged.


LIN is an array of last invoice dates (previous) generated by mapping NIN  and AN into a LAMDA and then bumping NIN by 12 or 3 months depending if a is annual or not.
CALC is a LAMBDA function that is used to return a valid payroll date based on an input date d.  It returns the maximum payroll date PDS that's less than or equal to the date input d and also, if l is zero, then the payroll date from PDS must also be greater than the current payday PD.
VNIN is an array of valid new invoice dates (payroll dates) returned using CALC. It uses IFERROR to rerun CALC if there is no result after the first run. For the second run NIN is bumped by a year/quarter, based on a.
VLIN is an array of valid last invoice dates (payroll dates) returned by passing LIN into CALC.
MDIF is a LAMBDA used to return the month difference between a date input d and VLIN.
TRM is an array of terms for the invoices' current cycle. It will be 11-13 months (typically 12) for annual invoices and 2-4 months (typically 3) for quarterly invoices.  The +/- 1 month is a result of weekends and holidays being omitted as valid paydays. It's calculated by passing VNIN to MDIF.
MDIF is again used to calculate MACCR, the number of months accrued for an invoice (up to and including the current payday).
PCT is the accrued months as a percentage, calculated by dividing the number of months accrued MACCR by the length of the term TRM
EUR is the amount of euros that have accrued for each invoice based on PCT
DUE is a calculation of the portion of EUR that is not simply accrued, but also due. i.e. needs to be paid from the current payroll.
FRAC is a numerical representation of MACCR and TRM in case it proves useful.
Finally, Total Due, DUE and the Total Due & Accrued are returned in I8 and I11 in case it is helpful.

NA Locale
=LET(
   RNG,A:A, HLDAY,M:M, RTDAY,TODAY(),
   TDAY,IFERROR(1/(1/(J1*K2)),RTDAY),
   COL,LAMBDA(n, OFFSET(RNG, 1, n-1, COUNTIF(RNG,">0"))),
   IN,COL(1), AMT,COL(2), AN,COL(3),
   PDS,BYROW(SEQUENCE(36,1,-18), LAMBDA(n,  LET(
     d,EOMONTH(TDAY,n)+26-SEQUENCE(14),
     MAX(FILTER(d,(WEEKDAY(d,2)<6)*NOT(COUNTIF(HLDAY,d))))))),
   PD,MIN(FILTER(PDS,PDS>=TDAY)),
   QO,ABS(MOD(MONTH(IN),3)-MOD(MONTH(PD),3)),
   NIN,MAP(IN, AN, QO, LAMBDA(i,a,q, LET(
     d,DATE(YEAR(PD),IF(a, MONTH(i), MONTH(PD)+q), DAY(i)),
     IF(d<PD, EDATE(d, a*9+3), d)))),
   LIN,MAP(NIN, AN, LAMBDA(i,a, EDATE(i, a*-9-3))),
   CALC,LAMBDA(d,l, MAX(FILTER(PDS, (PDS<=d)*((PDS>=PD)+l)))),
   VNIN,MAP(NIN, AN, LAMBDA(i,a, IFERROR(CALC(i,), CALC(EDATE(i, a*9+3),)))),
   VLIN,MAP(LIN, LAMBDA(i, CALC(i,1))),
   MDIF,LAMBDA(d, DATEDIF(EOMONTH(VLIN,1)+1, EOMONTH(d,1)+1,"M")),
   TRM,MDIF(VNIN), MACCR,MDIF(PD), PCT,MACCR/TRM, EUR,PCT*AMT,
   DUE,SUM((VNIN=PD)*EUR),
   FRAC,RIGHT(" "& MACCR, 2)& LEFT(" ("& TRM& ") ", 5),
   IFNA(VSTACK(
     HSTACK("Aligned Payroll Date¹","Accrued²","PCT","Months","","Today"),
     HSTACK(VNIN, EUR, PCT, FRAC, "",
       VSTACK(
         RTDAY,"","Payday/Pay Period Ending³", PD,"",
        "Total Due",DUE,"","Total Due & Accrued",SUM(EUR),"",
         "¹Pay Period closest to (but not after) invoice due date",
         "²100% when 'Payment Due' = 'Payday'",
         "³First weekday (non-holiday) from the 25th backward."))),""))


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'm a bit unsure about the calculation due the date format in the first column. Here's a suggestion based on my interpretation. This requires Excel for Microsoft 365.
Pay date calculation

Using WORKDAY.INTL function - Microsoft Support to determine workday

here I've used US holidays from 2023-2026, please customize to match your weekend/holiday values



Define a formula for calculating pay dates, here named paydate:
=LAMBDA(dt, [payday],
  LET(
    payday, IF(ISOMITTED(payday), 25, payday),
    in_cur_month, WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt), payday + 1),
      -1, , us_holidays_2023_2026),
    in_prev_month, WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(YEAR(EDATE(dt, -1)), MONTH(EDATE(dt, -1)), payday + 1),
      -1,, us_holidays_2023_2026),
    IF(dt >= in_cur_month, in_cur_month, in_prev_month)
  )
)


For annual invoices
Using the formula for annual invoices for Most recent, enter in F2:
=LET(
    first_due, A2:A5,
    cur_date, J1,
    most_recent_paydate, LAMBDA(due,
        IF(due <= cur_date, paydate(due), paydate(EDATE(due, -12)))
    ),
    MAP(first_due, most_recent_paydate)
)


Quarterly invoices
For last payments, entered in E2:
=LET(first_due_date, A2:A13, num_months, C2:C13,
paydate(MAP(first_due_date, num_months, LAMBDA(d,m, EDATE(d, m - 1)))))



Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, we're not on the same page. The first payment is irrelevant for me although there is the "payment this year" column which is a helper. Regarding the last payment - maybe I should replace the word "last" with "the most recent". By way of example let's look at your due date on the line A2: With the first due date of 10.05.2024, the last or the most recent payment would be on 25.04.2024 as of today 22.10.2024. Another example: With the first due date of 10.11.2024, the last payment would be paid on 25.10.2023. I hope this clarifies my requirements a bit.

@DannyLo, I've updated the annual "most recent" calculation - please check whether it matches your requirement.
